# Session variables survive after logout

Tags: php, session

I will explain how to reproduce my problem:

1. Log into my page: session variables are set as `$_SESSION['logged'] = true` and `$_SESSION['id'] = 123`.
2. Inside the main menu, click the *log out* option. The code is like this:

   ```
   function logout()
   {
       session_start();
       $_SESSION['id'] = null;
       $_SESSION['logged'] = null;

       unset($_SESSION);

       session_destroy();

       require_once('Views/SessionExpiredView.php');
   }
   ```
3. In the session expired view I display a link to the login page; there, the session is null.
4. I click back on the browser, and click OK to resend information.
5. The session becomes again `$_SESSION['logged'] = true` and `$_SESSION['id'] = 123` and I am logged in again and able to see all the information related to the ID 123.

This is a security issue and I don't know what is happening.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the session is back again even if you reload the page explicitly using `F5` or `Shift+F5`?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: If I just logout and then refresh the page, the session variables seem to be dead but if I click after the f5 back on the browser and resend info, the session recovers the values when the user was active :(

Comment: As gordjelin says, when you resend the information, you are resending your login data, hence you get logged in again. Nothing complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 4:** You click back and click “Resend information” — that means that you have resent your previous POST information (apparently the login and the password) — so nothing unusual.

A hint: just make a redirect after logging the user in.

Comment: Yes as you said is normal behavior, I was stressed for no reason jeje, thanks a lot for your answer and your time :)

regards from Guadalajara Mexico :)

Answer (score 0):

Your step 4. is the problem, you click ok to resend the information, which is effectively your login information from step 1.

You are just logging in again...